# Google push.webhookUrlUnauthorized Error

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm using google calendar API with push notification, till yesterday it was working fine but today it gives me error : here it is.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Vary: X-Origin
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error=invalid_token
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 31 Oct 2015 06:43:59 GMT
Expires: Sat, 31 Oct 2015 06:43:59 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; p="1"; ma=604800
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://api.hustl.it/test.php"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://api.hustl.it/test.php"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push?hl=en) page of the Calendar API developer guide, a valid SSL certificate should be installed on the webserver. You can check it out first if the SSL certificate currently installed expired or was removed.

Also note that invalid certificates include

- Self-signed certificates.
- Certificates signed by an untrusted source.
- Certificates that have been revoked.
- Certificates that have a subject that doesn't match the target hostname.

Another important item to consider based on the page is that the domain in URL used in the `address` value should be registered in the [Google Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push?hl=en#registering)

Hope this helps!